# Losing values when constructing a Series from a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame `td` consisting of the following columns:

```
In [111]: td.head(5)
Out[111]:
         Date      Time    Price
0  2015-09-21  00:01:26  4303.00
1  2015-09-21  00:01:33  4303.00
2  2015-09-21  00:02:21  4303.50
3  2015-09-21  00:02:21  4303.50
4  2015-09-21  00:02:31  4303.25
```

My goal is to have a Series with Datetime and Price.

I tried:

```
s = pd.Series(td['Price'], index=pd.to_datetime(td['Date'] + ' ' + td['Time']))
```

But get the result:

```
>>> s
2015-09-21 00:01:26   NaN
2015-09-21 00:01:33   NaN
2015-09-21 00:02:21   NaN
2015-09-21 00:02:21   NaN
                       ..
2015-09-25 16:59:58   NaN
2015-09-25 16:59:58   NaN
2015-09-25 16:59:58   NaN
2015-09-25 16:59:59   NaN
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

All the values from "Prices" are NaN. Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a Series from a DataFrame column and passing in an index, the column will be *reindexed* according to the new index.

In your case, none of the labels in the newly created Datetime index were originally used to index the column `td['Price']`, so a Series of missing (`NaN`) values is returned.

The easiest solution is to pass in `td['Price'].values` instead:

```
>>> pd.Series(td['Price'].values, index=pd.to_datetime(td['Date']+' '+td['Time'])
2015-09-21 00:01:26    4303.00
2015-09-21 00:01:33    4303.00
2015-09-21 00:02:21    4303.50
2015-09-21 00:02:21    4303.50
2015-09-21 00:02:31    4303.25
...
```

Using `td['Price'].values` means that the values from the column are in a NumPy array: this has no index and pandas does not try to reindex the values.